# Normalize a Minimized winform in the Form_Closing event

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, visual-studio-2010, events

I have a test app with multiple forms, one being a crude kind of menu. When I select one of the other forms with a button click the menu form minimises. All good.

What I want to happen now is when I have finished with the second form and click the red cross I want the menu to open back up from the tray. Seems simple but Im pulling my hair out.

```
private void Form2_Closing(object sender,System.ComponentModel.CancelEventArgs e)
{
    var menu = FormControl.MainMenu;
    menu.WindowState = FormWindowState.Normal;

    e.Cancel = false;
}
```

FormControl is my class to ensure only one instance of MainMenu can be opened. The code works inside the button click event but I am unable to get any kind of form closed/closing event to trigger.

Comment: so basically your question is "Why my form closing event not triggering?" ?

Comment: well, if that is the problem yes. I included all the information because for all I know Windowstate may not work in that particular event or I might be using the wrong event etc.

Comment: Sounds to me you simply forgot to subscribe the event.  Use the lightning bolt icon in the Properties window.  And use FormClosing instead of Closing so you know when it is closing because the user is logging out or shutting down the machine.

Comment: @HansPassant Perfect:) put that as an answer and I will accept it. I knew it would be something silly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ok, your comment about *"Windowstate may not work in that particular event"* disturbed me so I made simple test:

1. Created Form1 and Form2
2. Added button and click event to Form1
3. Added FormClosed event to Form2

Button1 Click event handler:

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Form2 form2 = new Form2();
    form2.WindowState = FormWindowState.Normal;
    WindowState = FormWindowState.Minimized;
    form2.Show(this);//Passing Form1 as owner
    form2.Activate();
}
```

Form2 FormClosed event handler:

```
private void Form2_FormClosed(object sender, FormClosedEventArgs e)
{
    this.Owner.WindowState = FormWindowState.Normal;//change state of owner form
}
```

**Result:**
After program launches - opens Form1. After clicking button - Form1 minimizes and Form2 pops up. After closing Form2 - Form1 restores to normal state.

**Resume:** 
double check if your Form2 REALY suscribed to FormClosed or FormClosing event.

Answer (score 1):

```
form2.FormClosing += delegate 
                            {
                                var menu = FormControl.MainMenu;
                                menu.WindowState = FormWindowState.Normal; 
                            };
form2.ShowDialog(); //Or Show() whatever you wish.
```

Comment: I think `Show`, not `ShowDialog` (or he won't be able to open (say) `form3` from the menu window until he closes `form2`).